# Will specifying Spring dtd and xsd versions in configuration xmls cause any issues when migrating form 3 to 4

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, dtd

When we are doing spring upgrade from spring 3 to 4 we came across spring dtd and xsd versions hard coded in xmls like

> `spring-beans-3.0.xsd` or `spring-beans-3.0.dtd`

.Ideally this shouldn't be hard coded in xmls  since some spring jars will refer to 4[**from parent pom dependency**]  and some will  refer to 3 from **local xmls**.If I remove the version I am sure it should take from **classpath**[parent pom property].

**Will there be any other impacts if I remove the versions from xmls for dtd and xsd.**

For DTD :

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"  "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-3.0.dtd">
```

For XSD:

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
>     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd">

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: You should either use DTD or XSD not both. For the XSD the recommended approach is to use the version less one already. For DTD (you shouldn't be using those anymore actually) that isn't possible.

Comment: I am not using xsd and dtd in the same file.If I remove the version nos like spring-beans.dtd[ without version no]  in xmls will it create any conflicts.I bileave it should  be taken from classpath if we won't specify version for dtd/xsd in xmls.Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: As I stated that mechanism only works for XSD files NOT DTD files. This has to do with how those things are loaded (and as mentioned you should be using the DTD anymore, nor do I believe that after 2.0 the DTD is even being maintained (judging from the sources). So if yu set that to 3.0 or something else that probably miserably fails.

Comment: Actually judging from the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/BeansDtdResolver.html) of the class it should work for a DTD but only for 2.0 (as that is the only version present, so you will not get any new features).

Comment: But to answer your question, will it cause issues. It depends on which namespaces you use, sometimes the beans behind a namespace have changed considerably and have changed behavior. One thing that comes to mind is for instance `<context:property-placeholder />` Earlier versions used the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and the newer use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: Yes got it .Thanks for the detailed explanation.